# django the second html page not concting to the existing one

Tags: django, django-models, deployment, django-views, django-templates

i got the error , because I couldn't connect to other html  pages, so please help me to debug the error.

I want the output to show the connecting  html page, but the out put idegate there is no such a path.

app(view.py)
`from django.urls import path from django.views import View`

```
from .import views
```

```
urlpatterns = [path('',views.index,name='index'),

path('contact/', views.contact,name='contact')
]
```

Comment: Please share error information in details along with the code where it was exactly occurred. Also what exactly means connecting html page., are you including other html page , or redirecting to other html page

Comment: it is  rdirecting to other page ,but i can't conect with the next page.it's contact.html page